# Can you extend an entity in CSS?

Tags: css

This is probably a pretty basic question, but is it possible to extend an entity in CSS?
For example, if I have an entity defined with a bunch of styles:

```
.blah {
    clear: right;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    height: 71px;
    width: 600px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Could I create two entities that each extend this one, then add/change some styles, such that I could just only reference "blahFoo" and "blahBar" in jsp code?

```
.blahFoo {
    color: #036;
}

.blahBar {
    color: #630;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such inheritance in CSS. With [Sass](https://sass-lang.com), you can extend some `class` or `placeholder`, as you can read on its [doc](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend). However, in CSS, you could do something like this:

```css
/* Have common styles for different elements together */

.blah, .blahFoo, .blahBar {
    clear: right;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    height: 71px;
    width: 600px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Then set specific styles on each of them differently */

.blahFoo {
    color: #036;
}

.blahBar {
    color: #630;
}
```